# Intellij move caret to start/end code block - in non-source file?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm working on a migration project in which I have to interact with massive config files (30k+ lines commonly) written in a custom syntax. Luckily the syntax involves normal {} brackets.

In Intellij, though, I'm unable to jump between code blocks because it's just a plain .txt file. In .java files I can use C^[ or C^] to accomplish this.

Is there some setting I'm missing or do I have to write a plugin to count matching '{' '}' characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Settings | Editor | File Types and define a custom file type for your file format. This doesn't require writing a plugin, and custom file types do support brace matching and the keyboard shortcuts to jump to the start/end of a code block.